# How to install over the range microwave with a large gap between appliance and upper cupboard?

Tags: kitchens, appliances

My surrounding upper cabinets are 40 inches. My over the range cabinet is 20 inches. The microwave I am trying to install is 10 inches (whirlpool YWML55011HS). It's 400 cfm.
I want to install it 5 inches from the bottom of the adjacent 40 inch cabinets. The mounting kit is made to install directly under the over the range 20 inch cabinet. The mounting kit consists of a back template screwed to the wall where the back of the microwave sits as well as two through the cabinet 5 inch bolts that screw directly into the microwave top.

Any idea on how to safely install 5 inches from the over the range 20 inch cabinet?

I cannot seem to find the bolts in a longer version and that would be unstable.

2x4 structure is a bir challenging for me but I could do it.

Metal brackets would work but where to find?

Amy ideas?

[image: Microwave install]

Comment: Are you just looking for longer bolts with spacers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options for you:

1. (probably the easiest) Get a taller microwave hood. This hood is 10-ish inches tall. Very tiny compared to the usual ~16-17 inches of other more capacious microwaves, especially in internal height. A ~16-17 inch microwave will fit with no extra modifications to the cabinetry needed, if you're not dead set on the 5" open space underneath. Whirlpool has a ~17" unit with bigger internal height that is less expensive than the one you chose. Other companies may have useful units too.
2. Build or get built a cabinet or spacer box to make up the difference. A 2x4 grid (actually 3 1/2" wide) with a 3/4" plywood top and bottom would come to 5" high. A removable front plywood piece of the same species and finish as your existing cabinets would look reasonably like it's supposed to be there. The removable front would allow access for bolting the spacer cabinet up to the upper cabinet, and for bolting the microwave hood to the spacer cabinet. Bulldog or magnetic catches could hold the removable front in place. Glue and screw the 3/4" plywood pieces to the 2x4 grid for a firm support. Alternative to the 2x4 grid: a 5"-tall box with an open front, all made of 3/4" plywood of the same species and finish as your cabinets. This could be an open shelf for plate or tray storage for the kitchen.

Comment: Open shelf  or put a door (or doors) on it - dead spaces like that have a nasty habit of accumulating residents, and it would be an ideal location for baking sheets, for instance.

Comment: Thanks @triplefault I ended up following your advice and just getting a bigger device.